Extracting value from raster file using UTM coordinates in Python
I've been trying to get value from a raster file of a single band using UTM coordinates. But all I'm getting is a value of 0 for all the locations.
I have attached that part of the code where northing_list and easting_list are lists of northing and easting values. Each of the coordinates passed the check where it should be within the bounds. Also, I have tried different raster files too. Same result only.
Can anyone please tell me what's the problem?
print(northing_list)
print(easting_list)

green_band = 'raster.tif' 

length= len(easting_list)

with rasterio.open(green_band) as src:
    transform = src.transform
    for e in range(length):
        row, col = ~transform * (easting_list[e], northing_list[e])
        print(src.read(1))
        green_value = src.read(1)[int(row), int(col)]
        print(green_value)


That is a really poor way to do it.  While it should work (though I haven't checked your actual transform calculations and I'm assuming your coordinates are actually in the same CRS as your raster), you are reading the entire raster twice for each easting.
Instead use src.sample:
coordinates = list(zip(easting_list, northing_list))

with rasterio.open(green_band) as src:
    for i, values in enumerate(src.sample(coordinates)):
        x, y = coordinates[i]
        green_value = values[0]  # get values of first (and only) band
        print(x, y, green_value)

